# Difference between Group by queries with and without Having

Tags: sql, group-by

I'm new to SQL queries so I'm trying to understand the difference between a select query with and without having. In the task, I need to report the first login date for each player.
How the table is arranged:

```
+--------------+---------+
| Column Name  | Type    |
+--------------+---------+
| player_id    | int     |
| device_id    | int     |
| event_date   | date    |
| games_played | int     |
+--------------+---------+
```

The first attempt, in which I wrote having, was unsuccessful.

```
SELECT player_id, event_date as first_login FROM Activity 
GROUP BY player_id
HAVING MIN(event_date)
```

Failed Test

```
{"headers":{"Activity":["player_id","device_id","event_date","games_played"]},"rows":{"Activity":[[1,2,"2016-03-01",5],[1,2,"2016-05-02",6],[1,3,"2015-06-25",1],[3,1,"2016-03-02",0],[3,4,"2016-02-03",5]]}}
```

This option passed all tests:

```
SELECT player_id, MIN(event_date) as first_login FROM Activity 
GROUP BY player_id
```

Why is it impossible to write `HAVING` in the first option, what is the difference between queries?

Comment: `HAVING MIN(event_date) ` is invalid SQL to begin with.

Comment: By simplifying a bit, the `HAVING` clause is a `WHERE` clause that applies after the aggregation has been carried out. Just that. `HAVING MIN(event_date)` doesn't work because `MIN(event_date)` does not evaluate to a boolean output.

Answer (score 1):

`HAVING` as well as `WHERE` are both filtering clauses. You use `WHERE` to specify filtering condition **before** grouping takes place. You can use `HAVING` to further filter **grouped** results.

Below you can see some example of viewing all the customers from specific state - `WHERE` who spend more than 70$.  Here you need `HAVING` since you need to filter from grouped results. In order to see who spent more than 70$ you need to calculate how much they spent. I hope this clarifies your question.

```
SELECT oi.order_id, SUM(quantity * unit_price) total_spent, CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS fullname, c.state
FROM order_items oi
JOIN orders o USING(order_id)
JOIN customers c USING(customer_id)
WHERE c.state = 'VA'
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING total_spent > 70
ORDER BY order_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The HAVING clause is used to place conditions on groups created by the GROUP BY clause, similar to how the WHERE clause places conditions on columns.

You don't need a HAVING clause to solve this problem (as you noted). You might use a HAVING clause if you needed to report the first login date for each player *before or after a specific date*.

```
SELECT player_id, MIN(event_date) as first_login
FROM Activity 
GROUP BY player_id
HAVING MIN(event_date) > '2020-12-31'
```